# Problem with asp.net mvc and google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I'm just getting into asp.net mvc and jquery so this might be a "stupid" question.

I'm developing an mvc application which contains a Google Map.

I've used this blog post as an inspiration

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/10/using-google-maps-with-mvc-framework.html

and it's working as expected.

The problem occurs when I want to filter the map data.

The use case is the following:

1. I have a view with a list of element.
2. For each element I have a "Trace" link.
3. The link point to a controller actions and has the element id as parameter.
4. The controller action returns a view.
5. The view has some javascript that calls another controller actions
6. The controller action returns my map data as JSON
7. The script initializes a Google map and displays the JSON data on the map.

I run into problems at 4. The core of the problem is getting the id of the original element to the action that returns the JSON data.

This is what I have tried.

I've created a parameter class which has a public int id property. The map view is using this class as "View data class"

In the view I have added a hidden input field that get filled with the id value from the data class.

```
<input type="hidden" id="_lblId" value="<%=Model.Id%>"/>
```

After that I include the javascript files that should load the Map a get map data from the controller.

This is where I run into problems.

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
var id = parseInt($("#_lblId").val());
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
if (google.maps.BrowserIsCompatible()) {            
    $.getJSON("/Maptest/Element/Tracemap", {id: id},  initialise);
}
});
```

**Controller Action:**

```
public ActionResult Tracemap(int id)
    {

        var map = new Map();

        var tracedata = _dataRep.ListSkanningerPaaKomponent(Convert.ToInt32(id));
        map.Name = "trace for element - " +id;
        map.Zoom = 2;
        map.LatLng = new LatLng { Latitude = 0.0, Longitude = 0.0 };
        var cnt = 0;
        foreach (var t in tracedata)
        {
            cnt++;

            var trace = new Trace
                            {
                                Name = "Trace " + cnt,
                                LatLng = new LatLng {Latitude = (double) t.Lat,                  Longitude = (double) t.Long},
                                Dato = (DateTime) t.Dato,
                                Tid = (DateTime) t.Tid,
                                Person = t.PersonId
            };
            map.Add(trace);
        }

        return Json(map);

    }
```

If I set a breakpoint in the controller action it never gets called. If I debug the javascript the id value is correct.

Using firebug I get this error: 500 Internal Server Error. And the link it tries to call is this : http://localhost:63246/Maptest/Element/Tracemap?_=1254848265779&id=18

If I change the action parameter to a string. The break point gets hit, but then id is empty.

Any ideas how to solve this? Or other ways to get the element Id to the JSON controller action?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you might be experiencing is a url routing problem.  To get the id parameter in your controller, you'll need to make it part of your url:  "/Maptest/Element/Tracemap/18".

in your jQuery call, I would simply do this:

```
var url = "/Maptest/Element/Tracemap/" + id;
$.getJSON(url, null, initialise);
```

I'm not positive if you'll need the "null" for the data parameter.  Try with and without it.